# Gecko/Firefox support for HTML5 Notifications

Tags: javascript, html, w3c, specifications, html5-notifications

I'm wondering if there is any build-in support for the *HTML5 Notification* feature in Gecko browsers so far? Maybe some hidden developer thingy ?

I'm aware of WebKits `window.webkitNotifications` which works great, so, is there a Firefox implementation ?

**Update**

After searching and reading some W3C HTML5 specs, I'm maybe a little bit off here.
I can't find any Notification feature anywhere there. Am I facing wrong facts here? Is that just a "very own webkit implementation"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To start with your second question: no, it's not a WebKit-specific feature. But although a site called ‘html5rocks’ contains a [demo](http://studio.html5rocks.com/#Time) of this, Notifications are still not part of HTML 5. There was a discussion about them on the WHATWG [mailing list](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2010-February/thread.html#24923) this year (read the messages with subject ‘Notification API’). They are mentioned again in a [later message](http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2010-May/026488.html).

So, what do we have? A description of the [Notification API](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification) in Chromium. A W3C [Editor's Draft of a specification](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebNotifications/publish/), based on Chromium's API (but independent of HTML 5).

Mozilla mentioned Notifications as part of their [Prism project](https://mozillalabs.com/blog/2007/10/prism/). E.g., beginning with Prism 0.9 Notifications are [a part of Prism](http://mozillalabs.com/blog/2009/05/prism-10-launches-with-new-website/):

> The ﬁrst desktop integration features
>   made an appearance. These included
>   popup notiﬁcations and dock badging. A
>   special JavaScript ﬁle called
>   webapp.js contains Prism-speciﬁc code
>   for customizing a web app.

You can read on on the [Prism Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism):

> Prism is available as an extension for
>   Firefox 3 or as a standalone
>   application.

And from the [FAQ](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Prism/FAQ#Is_Prism_a_Mozilla_product.3F):

> Prism is the codename for the project,
>   and if the functionality provided by
>   Prism becomes a product or is
>   integrated into other products (like
>   Firefox), then it won't necessarily
>   continue to be called by this
>   codename.

Comment: I'm a little bit disappointed that safari 5 does still NOT implement the webkitNotifications. I think that's a great feature for modern web applications.

Comment: @jAndy: That's a shame, indeed! (But I don't think that's an answer to my downvote question ;)

Comment: That's true, I obviously gave you a +1 along with the correct answer, but I'm interested aswell who downvoted it. If there is anything wrong here he should let us know.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that **Web Notifications** will land in [FireFox (Aurora 22)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=594543) as well. IE10 and even Safari6 are currently [missing the party](http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications).

Answer (score 1):

There's a Firefox plugin called [ff-html5notifications](https://code.google.com/p/ff-html5notifications/) that acts as an adapter between the Chrome Notification API and Firefox' internal notification API, which then again uses native notification systems on the respective platform (Growl, libnotify).

Note that on Linux, non-html notifications are currently only working without images with [this version of the plugin](https://code.google.com/p/ff-html5notifications/issues/detail?id=32#c6).

Answer (score 0):

[Tab notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/tab-notifier/) adds this feature and works great.

Answer (score 0):

I've also found this gs script:
https://github.com/jhdxr/userscript-html-desktop-notification
It seems to require scriptish to work!